# macbook 16 pro remap key "Y" to key "Z"

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

I would like to remap key "y" to key "z" on my map. So on keyboard I would have Y and it would write Z and vice versa.
I don't want to change keyboard input source or language since in that case I loose all programming shortcuts and key position that I use.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those tasks best done with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) [freeware], because it doesn't involve getting dirty in the Mac's own keyboard mapping, you just add a new 'input language' of your own design. Ukelele provides the mechanism & GUI to modify & add your own keyboard maps.

Full documentation is provided.

Comment: Sure thanks man!

Comment: Is there no simpler solution, e.g. define a single key-maping in the system settings?